# Pest damaged central leader on young Thuja

Tags: growth, pest-damage, evergreens

It seems an insect chewed and effectively severed new tender growth at the topmost portion (central leader) of my young *Thuja plicata*:[image]

How will the tree respond to this? Does it continue growing vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another branch will become leader; For a tree that young it will look fine in a year,  Bigger conifers will also develop a new leader but it will take a few years of growth to develop a regular appearance. Sometimes a mature tree will always have an oddly shaped top.